# Remove white rectangle on top of Google Searchbox

Tags: css, google-chrome, overriding, search-box

I want to add a Google Searchbox to my website.
This is the code I found:

```html
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'Search-Engine ID';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<div class="gcse-searchresults-only"></div>
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
  <input class="input" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

It works fine, but I get a white rectangle on top of the Searchbox. At least in Chrome and FF. In Edge it is ok.
I tried a lot to get rid of that rectangle, added

```
.gsc-control-cse {
border: none;
background: none;
```

}

to my css and also tried to override Google's code with the !important code, but so far nothing works.
How can I get rid of this white rectangle on top of my Searchbox?
You can see my testpage here: https://www.patriciakaas.nl/test.php
The Searchbox is at the Bottom right.

Johanna

Comment: Do you mean above the searchbox or the search box itself is white? Maybe clear your cache?

Comment: I mean the white rectangle on top of the box where it says "Search". No it hasn't anything to do with clearing the cache.

Comment: For me, the searchbox is white. There is no box above it. In dev tools I can see that the div with class gcse-control-cse has no background or border because of your custom css. I'm on chrome 58.

Comment: Ovokuro, that is weird. Can you maybe paste the  gcse-control-cse code here? Becaus I have used several codes for that.
So I guess it is working. Must be a caching issue at my end then.

Comment: Ok. The last code I used did work. This is what I used in my css:
[code].gsc-control-cse, .gsc-control-cse-en {
 border:none !important;
 background:none !important;
}
[/code]
Thank you all for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
.gsc-control-cse, .gsc-control-cse-en {
    border:none !important;
    background:none !important;
}
```